# NodeJS Loopback: UpsertWithWhere multiple instances found

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a custom js file that I need to run as a cron job.

I have made a script in `/server/command/import_action.js` and contains the following snippet in a for-loop:

```js
Dish.upsertWithWhere({meal_id:meal.id} , dish, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
});
```

Its importing some of the items fine but then it gives me an error:

> There are multiple instances found.Upsert Operation will not be
>   performed!

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Did you manually set the column name `meal_id`?  If you didn't than the loopback column name is `mealId` and your where condition is failing silently because you misspelled the column name.

Else: this is generally intended behavior of an upsert and you'll have to do something like this:

```
let result = await Dish.find({where: {meal_id: meal.id}});
if (result.rows.length) {
    await Dish.updateAll({meal_id: meal.id}, dish);
}else {
    await Dish.create(dish);
}
```